# Data coming from API's are not appending in CSV file when the application run second time

Tags: c#, csv

My Code is generating a new file but not overriding the data when i am using while loop.
the data coming from 100 api's are not appending when the app run first time but at the second time it is appending I dont want to append it. I want to rewrite the complete data whenever it runs.

```
        class Program
            {
                static string[] OUTPUT = new string[1000];
                static int index = 0, index1 = 0;
                static string[,] url = new string[1000, 2];
                static string[,] url_Rx580 = new string[100, 3];

    static void Data_Rx580()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------------Starting Process for Rx580 GPU------------");
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    string result = get_data(url_Rx580[i, 0], i);
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                    string result1 = get_data(url_Rx580[i + 1, 0], i + 1);
                    if (result1 == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (i >= 98)
                    {
                        crypt_unit_data_parse(result, result1, i, url_Rx580[i, 2], url_Rx580[i + 1, 2], 12);
                    }
                    else if (i < 98)
                    {
                        coin_calc_data_parse(result, result1, 0, 12);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("API for RX580 : {0}", i);
                    Console.WriteLine("API for RX580 : {0}", i + 1);
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                string filename = "RX580-Profitablity";
                generate_excel(filename, index1, "12");

    static void generate_excel(string filename, int k = 0, string quantity = "10")
            {
                //  string path = "D:\\crypt-unit-data-" + data.updatetime + ".csv";
                //string strFilePath = @"D:\data-30th-March-New-11.csv";
                string drivepath = @"/home/hanzala/Desktop/NEW LATEST/Demo_webapp updated/Demo_webapp updated/";
                string strFilePath = drivepath + filename + ".csv";
                string strSeperator = ",";
                string column_name = "S.No,Coin Name,Coin Symbol,Coin Algorithm,Current Coin Price,Optimized Hashrate (H/s) per GPU,Default Hashrate (H/s) per GPU ,Total Optimized Reward/day in USD,Total Default Reward/day in USD, Total Optimized Reward/Month in USD,Total Default Reward/Month in USD, Total Optimized Reward/day in Coins,Total Default Reward/day in Coins, Total Optimized Reward/Month in Coins,Total Default Reward/Month in Coins,Optimized Power in Watts/GPU, Default Power in Watts/GPU, Price KWh in USD, Total Optimized Profit/day in USD,Total Default Profit/day in USD, Total Optimized Profit/Month in USD, Total Default Profit/Month in USD,Total Optimized Profit/day in USD (For " + quantity + " GPUs),Total Default Profit/day in USD (For " + quantity + " GPUs), Total Optimized Profit/Month in USD (For " + quantity + " GPUs),Total Default Profit/Month in USD (For " + quantity + " GPUs) ";
                StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();
                sbOutput.AppendLine(string.Join(strSeperator, column_name));
                //   sbOutput.AppendLine(string.Join(strSeperator, ""));
                //     sbOutput.AppendLine(string.Join(strSeperator, ""));
                for (int i = k; i < index; i++)
                {
                    sbOutput.AppendLine(string.Join(strSeperator, OUTPUT[i]));
                }


                // Create and write the csv file
                File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, sbOutput.ToString());
                // To append more lines to the csv file
                // File.AppendAllText(strFilePath, sbOutput.ToString());
                Console.Write("Total Currencies Data Retrieved : {0}\n", index - k);
            }

    static void Main(string[] args)
            {

    url_Rx580[73, 0] = "https://www.coincalculators.io/api.aspx?name=bitcoinote&hashrate=1622.76977&power=111.7&poolfee=0&powercost=0.04&difficultytime=0";
                url_Rx580[74, 0] = "https://www.coincalculators.io/API?name=bitsum&hashrate=1859.498&power=121.2&poolfee=0&powercost=0.04&difficultytime=0";
                url_Rx580[75, 0] = "https://www.coincalculators.io/API?name=bitsum&hashrate=1627.06243&power=111.1&poolfee=0&powercost=0.04&difficultytime=0";
                url_Rx580[76, 0] = "https://www.coincalculators.io/API?name=triton&hashrate=1893.7376&power=120.8&poolfee=0&powercost=0.04&difficultytime=0";
                url_Rx580[77, 0] = "https://www.coincalculators.io/API?name=triton&hashrate=1641.04751&power=122.1&poolfee=0&powercost=0.04&difficultytime=0";
while (true)
            {
                Data_Rx580();

            }

        }
```

These URLS are 100 I cannot paste all of them here.
What I am missing please help.
When I am running this code manually all the new data is updating with the previous one but with the while loop it is not overriding.

Answer (score 1):

A loop with no output, you have to control the loop output:

**while (true)**

This loop has no output, and you will never be able to exit.
you have to control it with a variable that you can change its value with a condition:

```
bool Exit = false;
while (!Exit)
{
    Data_Rx580();
    if (Condition)
    {
        Exit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to stop my code i want to generate a over rided csv file

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal: Think about what you're saying. You want to write an application that runs **from now until the end of time**? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Flater data coming from API's are not appending when the application run second time

Comment: ah ok, the code is not complete, I think you have to add a wait in the loop:
await Task.Delay (1000);

Comment: you can create a listener in your API, and that way you can execute the code only when there is new data, or you can create a WebJob if you have.

Comment: try to put a wait:

while (true)
            {
                Data_Rx580();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }

Comment: sorry but you are not understanding what I am trying to say

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal: That's not a response to my comment.